# Python Arduino Serial port data logger not writing to file

Tags: python-3.x

I am tinkering with an Arduino and a clock sensor which also has a temperature sensor. I would like to be able to log the data to an output.txt file however i have run into problems. 
The output.txt file is created but nothing is stored in it - just an empty file.

here is the code im using (it is borrowed)

```
    import serial

serial_port = '/com4';
baud_rate = 9600; #In arduino, Serial.begin(baud_rate)
write_to_file_path = "output.txt";


output_file = open(write_to_file_path, "a");
ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)
while True:
    line = ser.readline();
    line = line.decode("utf-8") #ser.readline returns a binary, convert to string
    print(line);
    output_file.write(line)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the reason but you can try make the file object in a context:

```
with open(write_to_file_path, "a") as output_file:
    # ...
    output_file.write(line)
```

this implicitly close the file once you finish the `with` part. If that works, it means your program is fine but some how the it does not flush your written data to the disk before your program ended.

Comment: I updated the while loop to ask for further data or quit, upon exit the file is closed, and this actually fixes the writing to file problem... Now I just have to work out how to put it all together...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, not what i'm finished with but it does address the issue 
    import serial

```
serial_port = '/com4';
baud_rate = 9600; #In arduino, Serial.begin(baud_rate)
#write_to_file_path = "C:\Users\XPS\Desktop\ardy\output.txt";
breaker = input("more data?")


output_file = open('text.txt', "w");
ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)
while breaker == 'y':
    line = ser.readline();
    line = line.decode("utf-8") #ser.readline returns a binary, convert to string
    print(line);
    output_file.write(line)
    breaker = input("more data?")

output_file.close()
```